# next.js - dev, staging AND production config? - respecting NODE_ENV?

Tags: next.js, nodeenv

The way we configure all of our apps for deployment, where I work, is by using the standard pattern of a `config` folder with a default config and then dev/staging/prod configs that can override this.

We are then passing in env values using the `next.config.js` `env` object.
Again - fairly standard way of doing things.
We use the Config library to pull data out of our config in order to populate the `env` object. Nothing odd about this.

So, we have a config folder with:

`default.json5 dev.json5 staging.json5 production.json5`

The problem is, when next.js is run with `next start`, it will always use `production.json5` regardless of what `NODE_ENV` we have set.

We're about to just bite the bullet and use a custom server, before we do, I thought I'd reach out to see if there's an obvious answer to this.

How to get next.js to respect the `NODE_ENV` and not blindly just pull in a `production` config on `next start` ?

Comment: In Next.js, the `NODE_ENV` environment variable only allows `development`, `production` and `test` as possible values. It is also used for various optimisations when building the app for production, which forces `NODE_ENV` to `production`. I'd recommend you use a different, custom environment variable if you need one to determine the environment you're in, and don't tie it to the `NODE_ENV` variable.